# How to create circle overlay with text-Google map

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I want to create a circle overlay in google map **with text inside it**.How can i do this.

```
   map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);

var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: centerPosition,
    map: map,
    fillColor: '#0000FF',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeColor: '#0000FF',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    draggable:true
});
```

I will share fiddle for this. http://jsfiddle.net/pVh3b/434/

I need a circle with text as shown below[image]

Text also should move when it is dragging.Can anyone please help on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is something that should get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/MSY9a/1/

Using [Infobox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/docs/reference.html#InfoBoxOptions) to create a text box in the center of the circle and adding a circle center_changed listener to update the position of the box.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'center_changed', function () {
    label.setPosition(circle.getCenter());
});
```

I hope it helps!
Cheers.

**Edit**: You can change the appearance of the box with CSS. Also, removing the option 'pane: "mapPane"' seems to put it above the circle. Here is something that looks a little bit more like your example: http://jsfiddle.net/MSY9a/2/

**Edit 2**: Previously linked fiddle used external Infobox link that was since removed. Updated fiddle, links to Infobox on GitHub:
http://jsfiddle.net/MSY9a/291/